# Maven make phase conditional

Tags: maven-2

I want to make some phases optional say if compile fails or test fails and complete other phases like checkstyle, findbugs. Can i do that in maven, i have done it in ant not sure how to go about in maven

Answer (score 2):

Maven has no means to dynamically add or remove goals or lifecycle phases. Yes, you could probably achieve functionality like that by writing a plugin and using the `<extension>` mechanism, but you would be breaking standard conventions.

But all plugins you talk about have parameters you can set to not fail the build:

- `compiler:compile` has the [failOnError](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError) parameter
- `surefire:test` has the [testFailureIgnore](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) parameter
- `findbugs:check` has the [failOnError](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#failOnError) parameter
- `checkstyle:check` has the [failsOnError](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#failsOnError) parameter

My suggestion would be to have a profile where you add configurations with all of these parameters, so you can toggle all of them with a single command.

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution to me while still staying true to Maven conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to write your own small plugin for Maven in order to handle this. You may want to see this thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg95552.html

Answer (score 0):

Maven encourage you to play with "goal-to-phase assignments", instead of explicit instructions about when to run what. Maven [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is your roadmap, which you can't change. And on every milestone (*phase*) in this roadmap you can do certain operations (*goals*). In other words, you have to forget Ant and start using Maven :)